# How to tell the difference between the models of slipfighter?

Tags: spaceship, andromeda

Andromeda Fandom lists 3 different models of slipfighter on the [Andromeda Ascendant](https://andromeda.fandom.com/wiki/Andromeda_Ascendant): [Centaur](https://andromeda.fandom.com/wiki/RF-42_Centaur_Tactical_Fighter), [Phoenix](https://andromeda.fandom.com/wiki/AF/A-29_Phoenix) and [Shrike](https://andromeda.fandom.com/wiki/RA-26_Shrike). I had never noticed before that there was more than one type. Are there on-screen differences between the three types and if so what are they? (Basically I'm wondering if while watching an episode I can tell which model of slipfighter is being utilized.)

Also, in the episode "And Your Heart Will Fly Away", Harper mentions a "new slipfighter" - which is later seen in the episode (as Tyr steals it). Is this "new slipfighter" a totally new model appearing for the first time, or just a refit of one of the previously-seen models?

Comment: I'm not convinced that the latter two actually exist. The only mentions I can find are a verbal reference in a single episode and a bunch of fan-created content.

Comment: @Valorum which episode has the verbal reference? (I know arc light slipfighters are mentioned in the sole episode in which they appear, but those aren't attached to the andromeda) As far as I know there was a load of material published alongside the show, kind of like an encyclopedia or show bible, which I assume Andromeda Fandom is sourced from. If different types of slipfighter do appear in the show (e.g. different CGI models or interior sets), regardless of if they are explicitly named on-screen, I'd still be interested to know the different models.

Comment: http://www.chakoteya.net/Andromeda/208.htm - Mention of Shrikes here, but not seen on screen

Comment: A lot of those wiki articles just seem to be fan-work nonsense rather than anything created by the studio

Comment: @Valorum I found the reference, it's an official encyclopedia website authorized by the studio, which was originally hosted at andromedatv.com but now no longer online. There is a backup at http://www.saveandromeda.com/allsystems/index.htm for example http://www.saveandromeda.com/allsystems/ships/shrike.htm and http://www.saveandromeda.com/allsystems/ships/centaur.htm and http://www.saveandromeda.com/allsystems/ships/phoenix.htm - and see http://www.saveandromeda.com/allsystems/ships/xmc.htm where it mentions the different types of support craft carried by the Andromeda

Comment: @KidBuria - I'd be very interested to see how much of that was actually hosted on official sites. Hmm. Time to play with wayback machine..